# How to parse XML in Excel 2011 for Mac?

Tags: xml, excel, vba, macos, parsing

I have some VBA code for accessing various XML-based web APIs from **Excel (2007, 2010)**, and have just run up against a user who is on a Mac running **Excel 2011**. The code I've developed depends on a reference to MS XML 6.0, which apparently isn't available on the Mac.

This [seems to be a problem](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macexcel/in-excel-2011-what-vba-references-replace-the/ac8b4604-4d74-4e78-989e-ec6c301a5f08?msgId=deffe985-93df-4560-b796-9569aea70931) others have run up against with no resolution.

1. Does anyone know of a replacement for MS XML 6.0 on the Mac, or a workaround?
2. Is it possible for the user to just download and install the relevant .dll?

Comment: I am not aware of a VBA alternative but see if this interests you? http://www.editix.com/features/xquery_editor.html

Comment: I'm not developing an XML doc, just parsing it but thanks for the link. I'm sure my code could be rewritten with `Find` so it's cross-system compatible but I can't believe there's no support for parsing XML using the DOM in the Mac implementation of VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One cross-platform solution is to use a QueryTable *[like this one](http://numbers.brighterplanet.com/2011/01/06/using-web-services-from-excel/)*, that would certainly be better than rolling your own xml handler for the mac.

Comment: I like the look of that. I hadn't seen the Google Docs implementation though. That's really sweet!

Comment: Yeah but it's google which effectively makes it completely unfit for business use in my experience.  :)

Comment: Agreed. An implementation of `importXML()` that works in Excel would be great.

Answer (score 2):

I see that your first question has been answered.  For your second question: no, the Mac user cannot just install the appropriate .dll.  DLL is a Dynamic Link Library, which provides Windows applications with specific functionality.  Neither OS X nor Excel:Mac can do anything with a DLL file, just as OS X can't do anything with a Windows executable .exe file.  If rewriting the code to make it work cross-platform isn't in the cards, you could ask your Mac user to run Excel 2010 via a virtualization application or by dual-booting into Windows.