# How to parse XML and Store in array in Mac OS using VBA?

Tags: arrays, xml, macos, vba

I am working on Template (.dotm file) of Ms Word. I want it to work with both Windows and Mac OS.

I have parse XML and store data in Array and it is working perfectly as expected. But is is not working if I check in Mac.

Windows Code:

```
 Dim oXMLFile As Object
 Dim XMLFileName As String
 Dim Sites As Object
 Dim Names As Object
 Dim URLs As Object

 Set oXMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
 XMLFileName = "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Files\Test.xml"
 oXMLFile.Load (XMLFileName)
 If oXMLFile.Load(XMLFileName) Then
   ' The document successfully to load.
Else
   ' The document failed to load.
End If

Set Sites = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("TestClass/TestObject/Site/text()")
Set Names = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("TestClass/TestObject/Name/text()")
Set URLs = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("TestClass/TestObject/URL/text()")
```

I use this array of `Sites`, `Names` and `URLs` for further functionality. Above code working fine in Windows but it doesn't work for Mac OS. I think `Microsoft.XMLDOM` doesn't support in Mac OS.

Can anybody please suggest me example or way to achieve above functionality in Mac OS?

Comment: Have you read [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211308/how-to-parse-xml-in-excel-2011-for-mac)? Apparently MS XML is not available for the Mac, so you will need to find another way to parse the XML.

Comment: @Tim Thank you. I have read but I am not getting how to get all data of from XML. My XML file is stored in Document folder. Can you please suggest me any appropriate solution in my case? Here is my XML file data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37877170/not-able-to-get-data-from-xml-file-in-vba/37877623#37877623

Comment: Sorry about that. I guess I should have clicked through the link in that post to see that it had nothing to do with parsing XML in OSX. There is a [GitHub project](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-XML) that is incomplete and under development but claims to work for Excel for Mac 2011. Maybe it has some code that can point you in the right direction?

Comment: @Tim I am new for Mac. I am little confuse. I have read github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-XML. In given Example on this link there is a code Set XML = XMLConverter.ParseXML(), Can I pass my XML file path like "Document:TestFolder:TestFile.xml"?

Comment: @Tim If I can't pass file path, please suggest any other way if possible.

Comment: I gotta be honest. I haven't worked on an Apple product since the Apple IIe. xD I do know you can run an AppleScript from VBA though. Perhaps there is an AppleScript that can parse the XML and return it to VBA as a text file that is parsable by Excel. Everything I read opines about the lack of XML support in Office for Mac. Sorry I can't be much more help. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115302/discussion-between-nanji-mange-and-tim).

Comment: @Tim Is it possible to convert XML file in Text file (as you said) and read line by line and get data from it and Git Hub project suggest?